Redirect use on dev tools open
I was trying to protect the url of an embedded video on my site. To do this I can't let my users access the devtools and inspect the player. There are a lot of sites that have successfully achieved this, https://www.muya.et/, https://www.sflix.to and a lot more. How can I implement this in next.js.
"use client"
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

const DetectDevTools = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const detectDevTools = () => {
      const devtools = /./;
      devtools.toString = function() {
        router.push('/devtools-detected'); // Replace with your desired redirect path
        return 'devtools-detected';
      };
      console.log(devtools); // This will trigger the `toString` method when devtools are open
    };

    // Execute detection once when the component mounts
    detectDevTools();
  }, [router]);

  return null;
};

export default DetectDevTools;

I tried doing this, It works find on FireFox, but on every other browser it gives false positives and redirects every time, even with devtools not open.
I want the component to redirect only when the devtools is open, and should work on all major browsers.
